# Changing material on skinned mesh

Tags: three.js

I want to change the materials on SkinnedMesh imported from a Collada file with Blender (... to obtain a metallic effect).
As soon as one material is replaced the respective vertices are not affected by their bones anymore and won't move.
The materials are replaced in the collada loader callback before the mesh is added to the scene.

Any suggestions on how to change the materials without breaking the rigging?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show your code in your post. Did you fail to set `material.skinning = true;`?

Comment: God grief. Of course I did not. Thanks for the help and the nice welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are loading a `SkinnedMesh`, you can replace a material in the loader callback, but be sure to set

```
material.skinning = true;
```

three.js r.90